# setText() for custom Dialog box causing app to crash

Tags: android, android-layout

I have started developing in android. I am trying to do a word game, at the end I should be displaying the players result in a dialog box. I have a textView in the layout and when trying to use setText() the app crashes. Otherwise the custom dialog gets displayed. Need help.

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.butt_submit:
            puzzword.validateAnswer();
            puzzword.resetStrings();
            init();
            if(count==10){
                showScore();
                count=0;
               // finish();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.butt_share:
            break;
    }
   }


public void showScore(){
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1_layout);
    d.setTitle("Your Score");
    TextView correctAns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctAns);
    correctAns.setText("Correct Answers");
    d.show();
}
```

Layout file for the custom dialog box is here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/back_color">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/correctAns"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wrongAns"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/correctAns"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the crash messsage in your logcat?

Comment: You need to call `findViewById()` on the `Dialog` object to get reference to the `TextView`.

Comment: I am getting this error in logcat

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to get the view from the activity content view and not from the dialog view hirarchy.
Instead of :

```
TextView correctAns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctAns);
```

Write:

```
TextView correctAns = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.correctAns);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView correctAns = (TextView)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.correctAns);
```